# how to convert a tree to a simple expression?

Tags: python, recursion, tree

Based on the program [here](https://github.com/moshesipper/tiny_gp/blob/856d9a6245e9b4b4f891a1242a42213a8c54cb31/tiny_gp_plus.py),
a tree like this be created:
[image]

main code:

```
def add(x, y): return x + y
def sub(x, y): return x - y
def mul(x, y): return x * y
FUNCTIONS = [add, sub, mul]
TERMINALS = ['x', -2, -1, 0, 1, 2] 
class GPTree:
    def __init__(self, data = None, left = None, right = None):
        self.data  = data # the node data can be a function n FUNCTIONS or a terminal in TERMINALS
        self.left  = left
        self.right = right
        
    def compute_tree(self, x): # recursive function
        if (self.data in FUNCTIONS): 
            return self.data(self.left.compute_tree(x), self.right.compute_tree(x))
        elif self.data == 'x': return x
        else: return self.data
```

but because **compute_tree****(self, x)** is not effecient enough and can't be easily supported by numba, I would like to convert the tree to a simpler and more direct expression or function before applying it to every row of a numpy array.
so for this example I would like to convert it to:

```
simple_representaion_tree(x)= add(mul(x,add(1,x),sub(0,-1))
```

can **compute_tree** be altered to produce **simple_representaion_tree****(x)** or a string that can later be converted to **simple_representaion_tree****(x)** ?

Comment: isn't that already exactly what it does?

Comment: sure, but efficiency and speed matters. I think the simple_representaion_tree will be faster especially with numba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Believe what you are looking for is this :

```
    def add(x, y): return x + y
    def sub(x, y): return x - y
    def mul(x, y): return x * y
    
    FUNCTIONS = [add, sub, mul]
    TERMINALS = ['x', -2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
    
    class GPTree:
        def __init__(self, data=None, left=None, right=None):
            self.data = data
            self.left = left
            self.right = right
    
        def compute_tree(self, x):
            if self.data in FUNCTIONS:
                return self.data(self.left.compute_tree(x), self.right.compute_tree(x))
            elif self.data == 'x':
                return x
            else:
                return self.data
    
        def get_simple_representation(self):
            if self.data in FUNCTIONS:
                return f"{self.data.__name__}({self.left.get_simple_representation()}, {self.right.get_simple_representation()})"
            elif self.data == 'x':
                return 'x'
            else:
                return str(self.data)
```

Here is how to achieve your desired results:

```
# Create a tree
tree = GPTree(add,
              GPTree(mul, 'x', GPTree(add, 1, 'x')),
              GPTree(sub, 0, -1))

# Compute the tree
x = 3
result = tree.compute_tree(x)
print("Result:", result)

# Get the simple representation
simple_tree = tree.get_simple_representation()
print("Simple Tree:", simple_tree)
# Create a function from the simple representation string
function = eval("lambda x: " + simple_tree)

# Test the function
x = 3
evel_result = function(x)
print("Eval Result:", evel_result )

# Now Check The Reuslts
print("Eval Result == Result : ", evel_result==result)
```

Outputs :

```
Result: 7
Simple Tree: add(mul(x, add(1, x)), sub(0, -1))
Eval Result : 7
Eval Result == Result : True
```

---

For a more performant code utilize Memoization and avoid String Concatenation. Like Following :

```
def add(x, y): return x + y
def sub(x, y): return x - y
def mul(x, y): return x * y

FUNCTIONS = {add: 'add', sub: 'sub', mul: 'mul'}
TERMINALS = {'x': 'x', -2: '-2', -1: '-1', 0: '0', 1: '1', 2: '2'}

class GPTree:
    def __init__(self, data=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def compute_tree(self, x, cache=None):
        if cache is None:
            cache = {}

        if self.data in FUNCTIONS:
            if (self.data, x) in cache:
                return cache[(self.data, x)]
            else:
                result = self.data(self.left.compute_tree(x, cache), self.right.compute_tree(x, cache))
                cache[(self.data, x)] = result
                return result
        elif self.data == 'x':
            return x
        else:
            return self.data

    def get_simple_representation(self):
        stack = []
        node = self
        while node or stack:
            while node:
                if node.data in FUNCTIONS:
                    stack.append(FUNCTIONS[node.data])
                    stack.append('(')
                    node = node.left
                elif node.data == 'x':
                    stack.append(TERMINALS[node.data])
                    node = None
                else:
                    stack.append(str(node.data))
                    node = None
            if stack:
                if stack[-1] == '(':
                    stack.pop()
                    stack.append(', ')
                    node = node.right
                elif stack[-1] == ', ':
                    stack[-1] = ')'
                    node = node.right
                else:
                    node = None

        return ''.join(stack)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit of an attempt, I might try to refine that if needed:

Basically this replaces `compute_tree(x)` by `compute_tree()(x)`.

I'm not sure that's what you are after, though

```
def compute_tree(self):
    if callable(self.data):
        left = self.left.compute_tree()
        right = self.right.compute_tree()
        if callable(left) or callable(right):
            return lambda x: self.data(
                left(x) if callable(left) else x,
                right(x) if callable(right) else x,
            )
        else: return self.data(left, right)
    elif self.data == 'x': return x
    else: return self.data
```